# QMake and wxWidgets (External Libraries)

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, qmake

I'm trying to compile a GUI program based on the wxWidgets libraries. I get a lot of undefined references to "something". I tried to add a few libraries manually on the LIBS variable of QMake without success. How can i add all the wxWidgets libraries to QMake without hard coding each library? Below is my .pro file.

```
# simple.pro
TARGET = sample

HEADERS += main.h simple.h
SOURCES += main.cpp simple.cpp

LIBS += -LC:/SourceCode/Libraries/wxWidgets2.8/lib/gcc_dll/wxmsw28_core_gcc.dll \
        -LC:/SourceCode/Libraries/wxWidgets2.8/lib/gcc_dll/wxmsw28_gcc.dll \
        -LC:/SourceCode/Libraries/wxWidgets2.8/lib/gcc_dll/wxmsw28_aui_gcc.dll

INCLUDEPATH += C:/SourceCode/Libraries/wxWidgets2.8/include

CONFIG += release
```

The errors are of the form:

> release/simple.o:simple.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV6Simple[vtable for
>   Simple]+0x320): undefined reference to
>   `wxFrameBase::SetStatusBar(wxStatusBar*)'

Comment: What are the errors you're getting? And just curious, but why use wxWidgets when you seem to have Qt at your disposal?

Comment: sample error message : release/simple.o:simple.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV6Simple[vtable for Simple]+0x320): undefined reference to `wxFrameBase::SetStatusBar(wxStatusBar*)'. This is just one of many many error message of the same kind.

Comment: Btw, you should not try to link against DLLs but against their corresponding .lib files

Comment: I'm on winXP SP2 using MinGW and have .a file corresponding to .dll. Will that be ok? and what exactly is the difference and does it affect the fact that they could not be located?

Comment: I don't use MinGW, so I'm not 100% sure, but it might be worth a try. :) As for the difference, with some abstraction you could say that the .lib/.a contains information on what is available in the DLL and where in the DLL this can be found. This is the information the linker needs and seemed to be missing.

Comment: @Bart: i tried changing .dll to corresponding .a and manually add even more libraries as seen from the directory, still have the same error messages, "undefined reference to XXXXXXXXX".

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to use the .a files to add to the linker.

Then you need to define WXUSINGDLL if you link against the shared libraries.

Additionally, you forgot

```
 wxbase29u.a
```

Hope that helps.